# There are two new lines in database, but only one new line counted in Javascript

Tags: jquery

I really confused with this, I have a value taken from database which has two new lines. But then, I'm using .length in jQuery, and it only counts 1 line.

this is the code I'm using:

```
let text = $('#signature').text().length;
console.log(text);
```

It should be '9' (7 + 2 newlines), but the result is '8'

this is the data in the database:
[image]

This is the value that I print in the console: [image]
Thanks for the help

Comment: It's kind of hard to digest your database information.  Does `SELECT COUNT(*)` return 9 records, or just 8?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen No, it's only 1 record, what I need to count is the length of the string

Comment: Can you add the output of `$('#signature').text()` here?

Comment: id is for unique identity you should use class in jquery and html.

Comment: @rhog23  Could you please clearly describe your question. The question description itself causing a bit confusion for readers. The string you specified "Testing" has length 7 but you are saying the exact length is 8. Then your below statement is difficult to digest : "It should be '9' (7 + 2 newlines), but the result is '8' "    . Are you considering new lines in the DB as a single character. Going forward, please mention enough description of the Question.